# Como funciona a criptografia de dados no Firebase?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, firebase, criptografia

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo de mensagens Android utilizando Firebase e percebi que será necessário proteger os dados dos usuários e as mensagens trocadas por eles, pois no momento é possível ver tudo pelo console do Firebase (o que provavelmente facilita uma invasão) mas não estou encontrando muita coisa sobre isso. Como funciona?

Os dados são nome, foto de perfil, email, apelido, bem como as mensagens trocadas em cada sala de bate-papo.

Comment: Humm.. deixa eu ver se eu entendi.. você quer que as mensagens fiquem criptografadas dentro dos token do firebase ?

Comment: Não tenho muita experiência com desenvolvimento assim, mas acredito que nem os desenvolvedores podem ter acesso às conversas dos usuários, não é? @Matheus

Comment: Ai depende da politica da empresa ou do próprio desenvolvedor... Mas acho que o firebase não tem este recurso, mas você poderia criar sua própria criptografia e salvar no firebase os dados já criptografados, e quando for receber estes dados você poderia descriptogra-los

Comment: Ignorando o Firebase em si, você armazena as chaves públicas (ou algo que permita a derivação de chaves).  Por simplicidade (min. seguro, não ideal) cada usuário gera dois pares de chaves (RSA/Curve25519), uma para assinar e outra para encriptar (receber mensagens). Quando iniciar uma conversa o cliente pede a chave pública da pessoa, então envia a mensagem, criptografada e assinada, mas isso é LENTO. Uma outra forma  seria algum ECDH (e talvez usar alguma derivação de chave), assim poderia criar uma chave simétrica entre duas partes e usar um ChaCha20Poly1305 ou AES-CBC + HMAC ou AES-GCM.